# Multiply each element in a matrix by each element in a vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, octave

I have an `mxn` matrix, `M`, and a vector, `b`, (length `c`). Is there a way of multiplying each element of `M` by each element of vector to get an `mxnxc` result, i.e. `result(1, 1, :)` is `M(1, 1) .* b`?

For vectors, using the element-wise operators works. E.g. if `m = [a; b]` and `n = [c d]` then `a .* b` gives

```
a*c  a*d
b*c  b*d
```

but for matrices, this will perform the element-wise operation column-wise or row-wise on the matrix, depending on whether `n` is a column or row vector. E.g. if `m = [ a b; c d ]` and `n = [ e f ]` then `m .* n` gives

```
a*e  b*f
c*e  d*f
```

while the result I'm looking for would be `result(:, :, 1) =`

```
a*e  b*e
c*e  d*e
```

and `result(:, :, 2) =`

```
a*f  b*f
c*f  d*f
```

I know this can be achieved using a loop,

```
result = zeros(m, n, c);
for i = 1:b
  result(:, :, i) = M .* b(i); 
end
```

but I'm wondering if there is a simpler, i.e. more`MATLAB/Octave` (usually more readable and performant) way, of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to permute/reshape `b` along the third dimension, and let [implicit expansion](https://nickhigham.wordpress.com/2016/09/20/implicit-expansion-matlab-r2016b/) do its work:

```
result = M.*reshape(b,1,1,[]);
```

For older Matlab versions use [`bsxfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
result = bsxfun(@times, M, reshape(b,1,1,[]));
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing the grammar in the question too.